# Same results with \b meta character with it vs without it

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm learning regular expressions in JavaScript and the problem I am facing is i'm trying to understand why the \b meta character is so special to use? I see no difference by not using it vs using it so what is the difference between using it and not using it? This is what I mean.

**WITH \b**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to do a global search for "W3" at the beginning or end of a word in a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Visit W3Schools"; 
    var patt1 = /\bW3/g;
    var result = str.match(patt1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**WITH OUT \b**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to do a global search for "W3" at the beginning or end of a word in a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Visit W3Schools"; 
    var patt1 = /W3/g;
    var result = str.match(patt1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I already know what it means by definition by reading it but i'm simply just questioning why use it if it produce the same thing in the above 2 code examples? If any one can show me 2 code examples to show how they will give different results I will really appreciate that. I even move the match in the middle but it still gave me the same result as with out using it.

**SOURCE**

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_begin.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\b means a "word-break" character (listed here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions -> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.6)

```
var str = "aaaé";
var patt = /\baaa\b/;    
var result = str.match(patt); /* match it */
```

but

```
var str = "aaab";
var patt = /\baaa\b/;    
var result = str.match(patt); /* doesnt match it */
```

Comment: Thanks it now it makes since this is going based on the beginning or the end of a selected match for example I notice if I did this \bW3 it will match but if I put this instead W3\b it wont match because of the string EX  Visit W3Schools same thing with schools if I do this \bSchools it wont work but it will work with this instead Schools\b . So thank you so much @romph and every one! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Both of your examples fail to do what the html claims they are going to do.  Go to https://www.regextester.com/ and use `blahW3blah`, `W3blah`, and `blahW3` as your test strings.  Your regex should match the last two, but not the first.

You need:
`(\bW3|W3\b)`

(Match W3 at the beginning of a word (`\bW3`) OR (`|`) match W3 at the end of a word (`W3\b`)